# Uno Plataform Android and UWP: how copy file to local folder?

Tags: android, image, uno-platform

I'm trying to pick pictures files and copy them to app local folder, and save path as string in database to display images, the code works fine on UWP but does not on Android (I'm using Uno Platform):

```
    string SImag = string.Empty;

    private async Task<string> MediaxPicAsync()
    {
        Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".gif");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (file != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Windows.Storage.StorageFile temp = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("TempFile." + file.FileType);

                await file.CopyAndReplaceAsync(temp);
                return temp.Path;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Could not open image!", "Error image loading").ShowAsync();;
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Xaml Code:

```
<Image>
     <Image.Source>
         <BitmapImage UriSource="{x:Bind SImag, Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource appClsConvStr2Imag}}" />
     </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Converter:

```
public class ClsConvStr2Imag : Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter
    {
        object Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                string sPath = (string)value;
                if (sPath.Contains("/") | sPath.Contains("\\"))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    if (parameter == null)
                    {
                        sPath = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\" + sPath;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sPath = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\" + parameter + "\\" + sPath;
                    }
                }
                return new Uri(sPath);
            }
        }

        object Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

On Visual studio output during Android debug it shows error as:

```
[BitmapFactory] Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/Sale.Sale/files/TempFile.png (No such file or directory)
```

Any help to overcome this issue is most welcome, I did research for 3 days and could not find clean solution for this issue. Many thanks in advance for time and expertise.

Comment: There is nothing with bitmapfactory in your code.

Comment: I do believe it is generated by Xaml on UI,